# The right layout for a curved set of buttons?

Tags: android

I'm working on creating a menu screen, its fairly boring set of buttons so I wanted to add a curve to their layout to make it a bit more interesting. Like this:

[image]

I've just added the curved line to give an idea of what I'm doing - it won't actually have a line when done.

My question is what is the best way to go about doing this. I have tried using a linear layout and then applying a left padding to push them increasingly away from the edge. The problem here is that this depends on the screen size. On a small screen it displays fine and on a larger screen it does not. The second problem I have it that I'd like the entire curve to be centralized in the screen. Should I use a linear layout nested inside another?

If anyone has any ideas or sample layout xml as the best way to achieve this that'd be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look on [this widget](https://github.com/siyamed/android-satellite-menu), they doing someting like this

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I want to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a [relative layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html) so you can the position of each button relative to the one that comes below it?